# Клавиатура на json для телеграмм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бота для телеграмм, необходимо отправить текст на кнопке, но без ссылки.
И ещё мне необходим пример, того как можно написать клавиатуру в несколько рядов, к примеру в два на json.

Код которым я сейчас пользуюсь:

```
import json

keyboard = {
        "inline_keyboard": [[
            {
                "text": 'some text',
                "url": "some url"
            }
        ]]
    }

data = {
    "chat_id": some_chat_id,
    "text": 'some text',
    "reply_markup": json.dumps(keyboard)
}
```

Код который выше для одного ряда и на одну кнопку.

Таким образом я отправляю запрос на Телеграмм:

```
async with ClientSession() as session:
            await session.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot11111111:AAHCE/sendPhoto', data=msg)
```

Comment: какая библиотека используется ? У меня есть пример для pytelegrambotapi

Comment: @vladrunk правил.

Comment: @vladrunk зачем вы удалили ответ? Он мне помог, я собирался его отметить.

Comment: Переформатировал с результатом работы и полным примером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код у меня сработал.

```py
import json
import requests

keyboard = {
    "inline_keyboard": [
        [
            {
                "text": 'some text',
                "callback_data": "some callback_data"
            }
        ],  [
            {
                "text": 'some tex 2t',
                "callback_data": "some callback_data 2" 
            }
        ],
    ]
}

data = {
    "chat_id": 486850227,
    "text": 'some text',
    "reply_markup": json.dumps(keyboard)
}

print(data)

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/{botToken}/sendMessage', data=data)
    print(response.json())
```

Результат:
[image: Вывод консоли]

[image: Сам бот]